# Value is not appended in the tipArray and totalArray though code is syntactically right and i think logically as well

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, object

Please help me
The question is to calculate tip and total amount paid by a man using object and loop.
bill Amount given : 124, 48, 268, 180, 42 (all id $) Though it doesn't matter

1. Create an object with an array for the bill values
2. Add a method to calculate the tip
3. This method should include a loop to iterate over all the paid bills and do the tip calculations
4. As an output, crater 1 array containing all tips and another array containing final paid amount.

```
let billValue = {
  tipArray: [],
  totalArray: [],
  bill: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tipCalc: function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.bill.length(); i++) {
      switch (true) {
        case this.bill[i] < 50:
          tipValue = (20 / 100) * bill[i];
          totalValue = tipValue + this.bill[i];
          tipArray.push(tipValue);
          totalArray.push(totalValue);
          break;
        case this.bill[i] > 50 && this.bill[i] < 200:
          tipValue = (15 / 100) * bill[i];
          totalValue = tipValue + this.bill[i];
          tipArray.push(tipValue);
          totalArray.push(totalValue);
          break;
        case this.bill[i] > 200:
          tipValue = (10 / 100) * bill[i];
          totalValue = tipValue + this.bill[i];
          tipArray.push(tipValue);
          totalArray.push(totalValue);
          break;
        default:

      }
    }
  }

}
console.log(billValue.tipArray);
console.log(billValue.totalArray);
```

Comment: You need to call billValue.tipCalc() then only your logic will be executed

Comment: Please don't keep updating the question with suggestions from answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of an array is not a function, but a property.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.bill.length; i++)
```

You also need to call your `tipCalc` function before logging the arrays.

```
billValue.tipCalc();
console.log(billValue.tipArray);
console.log(billValue.totalArray);
```

You also need to use `this` to qualify access to properties of the object and enclose all your switch cases in blocks as variables cannot be redeclared in the same block with let. The corrected code is as follows:

```
let billValue = {
  tipArray: [],
  totalArray: [],
  bill: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tipCalc: function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.bill.length; i++) {
      switch (true) {
        case this.bill[i] < 50:{
          let tipValue = (20 / 100) * this.bill[i];
            let totalValue = tipValue + this.bill[i];
          this.tipArray.push(tipValue);
          this.totalArray.push(totalValue);
          break;}
        case this.bill[i] > 50 && this.bill[i] < 200:{
          let tipValue = (15 / 100) * this.bill[i];
          let totalValue = tipValue + this.bill[i];
          this.tipArray.push(tipValue);
          this.totalArray.push(totalValue);
          break;}
        case this.bill[i] > 200:{
          let tipValue = (10 / 100) * this.bill[i];
          let totalValue = tipValue + this.bill[i];
          this.tipArray.push(tipValue);
          this.totalArray.push(totalValue);
          break;}
        default:

      }
    }
  }

}
billValue.tipCalc();
console.log(billValue.tipArray);
console.log(billValue.totalArray);
```

Comment: thanks but again the value isn't appending into the array

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? What is the output?

Comment: I explained it above.

Comment: thanks a lot it solved the error and helped me alot

Comment: @Najup Happy to help.